# C++ in VSCode, Having Difficulty with Class Paths

Tags: visual-studio, path

I'm a mega noob. I was having difficulty getting my classes to work with inheritance in another program, so I looked up a simple inheritance project to trouble shoot.
[image: main]
The inheritance functions are implemented correctly
This is my file directory
[image: where all the classes/headers are]
of course when I run it, I get
[image: pathnotfound]
When I used java I could easily configure classpaths and what not, but with C++ i'm having difficulty seeing how to do this.

I know this is probably a no brainer, but as a newcomer, it feels like there are ten thousand ways to go about fixing something and it can be overwhelming if you're not decisive with what you should do.
I appreciate any help!

I tried going through different Command Palette options in VSCode to figure out how to configure classpaths in C++, but nothing is resulting from it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out, my cpp files were down too many subsequent folders, as opposed to being in the primary folder of the workspace. I'm sure you can add/alter this but for now I don't care and I just want it to work, so this is what I realized.